# mypy django models typehint

Tags: python, django, django-models, mypy

I integrated mypy into my project and would like to type my django models, how would I enable the following conversions? ForeignKey to the actual model, charField and textField to str, DecimalField to Decimal...

```
class mymodel(models.Model):
       address: str = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       description: str = models.TextField()
       organisation: Organisation = models.ForeignKey(
        "organisations.Organisation",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="properties",
        editable=False,
    )
```

My current setup.cfg file looks like this:

```
[mypy]
plugins = mypy_drf_plugin.main,  mypy_django_plugin.main, pydantic.mypy
exclude = /migrations/|template
python_version = 3.11
no_implicit_optional = True
strict_optional = True


[mypy.plugins.django-stubs]
django_settings_module = "backend.settings"
```

Comment: Remove the annotations. `models.CharField` is a descriptor that will evaluate to `str` on instance.

Comment: yes, but what about the foreign key, that will not be evaluated to Organisation

Comment: Why not? It happens in my code. And reverse managers are also added, thanks to the plugin.

Comment: When I don't type organisation, and do mymodel().organisation it gets type Any, not Organisation in vscode, so chaining won't work

Comment: It won't fly with `VSCode`, `django-stubs` rely on `mypy` a lot. Try `reveal_type(MyModel.objects().get().oganisation)` in your code and run `mypy` on it. IDE support won't be as good as real type checking.

Comment: that is a bummer, thanks anyway!